# Adding information to a Beamer title page

Tags: beamer, titles

I'm working on putting together a Beamer presentation and had a question.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\title{Screen Scraping with R}
\subtitle{}
\author{name}
\date{June 20, 2011}
\begin{document}
```

I want to add "Kansas City R Users Group" below the author, but I don't want it to be the subtitle. Can anyone tell me how to do that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use the `\institute{...}` field for this purpose:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\title{Screen Scraping with R}
\subtitle{}
\author{name}
\institute{Kansas City R Users Group}
\date{June 20, 2011}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```